# Php function adding unwanted line break at beginning of .ics file

Tags: javascript, php, icalendar

I have this code that was working but now it fails...

```
$v = new vcalendar(); // create a new calendar instance 
        $v->setConfig('unique_id', 'myWebsite'); // set Your unique id
        $v->setProperty('method', 'PUBLISH'); // required of some calendar software
        foreach ($valid_request as $key => $value) {
            $start_date = explode('-', $value->start);
            $start_time = explode(':', $value->from_time);
            $end_time = explode(':', $value->to_time);


            $vevent = new vevent(); // create an event calendar component
            $vevent->setProperty('dtstart', array('year' => $start_date[0], 'month' => $start_date[1], 'day' => $start_date[2], 'hour' => $start_time[0], 'min' => $start_time[1], 'sec' => $start_time[2]));
            $vevent->setProperty('dtend', array('year' => $start_date[0], 'month' => $start_date[1], 'day' => $start_date[2], 'hour' => $end_time[0], 'min' => $end_time[1], 'sec' => $end_time[2]));
            $vevent->setProperty('LOCATION', $_SESSION["location"]); // property name - case independent
            $vevent->setProperty('summary', $value->title);
            $v->setComponent($vevent); // add event to calendar
        }
        //print_r($v);

        $v->returnCalendar(); // redirect calendar file to browser
```

The problem I am having is when I go to the .ics file it generates, their is a space at the beginning of the file.

```
*space here*
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//myWebsite//NONSGML iCalcreator 2.4.3//
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
//then the rest of the code
```

If I manually go in and delete the space and try to manually import it works, so I am curious if anyone knows what my problem is or if this is a bug.

Comment: no chance your php file has a blank linefeed somewhere outside the code?

Comment: You have a space somwhere outside of opening and closing php tags. Like `_<?php` or `?>_`

Comment: This is what I assumed at first, I went through all the PHP pages that are connected and removed all the ending ?>php and ensure the top ones did not have a space before _<?php and still did not work.

Comment: What exactly dou mean by "it fails"?